# Gas fee too high for simple ERC20 token deploy

Tags: remix

I am trying to create/deploy a simple erc20 token code on mainnet

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

     import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
        contract ANGIEToken is ERC20 {
            address public admin;
            constructor() ERC20("ANGIE Token", "ANG") {
                _mint(msg.sender, 450000000 * 10 ** 18);
                admin = msg.sender;
            }
        
            function mint(address to, uint amount) external {
                require(msg.sender == admin, 'only admin');
                _mint(to, amount); 
            }
            
            function burn(uint amount) external {
                _burn(msg.sender, amount);
            }
        }
```

After deploy (with remix) it failed.
Reason:'{"value":{"code":-32000,"message":"intrinsic gas too low"}}'

Metamask tells me that it needs 1300 dollar. What am i doing wrong?

Gaslimit in remix is 3000000
Value is 0 wei

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you need $1300 with today's crazy gas prices. That sounds about right to me.

Comment: Perhaps you need to adjust remix 3M default gas. Deploy to rinkeby, the gas used should be the same on mainnet. Adjust remix 3M default, leave some room like gas used + 10%. Before deploying to mainnet multiply gas times gasPrice that should give how much ether you will need. If mainnet is still too much you may want to try one of the layer2 implementations.